Condition for triangle to 'fit' inside a rectangle
Consider a rectangle $ABCD$.
Take a point $N$ 'on' $CD$.
Call $AB = x$, $AN = a$ and $BN = b$.

What is the condition needed for $N$ to lie between $C$ and $D$? It is possible to choose $x$, $a$ and $b$ but then end up with $N$ to the 'left' of $D$ rather than between $D$ and $C$.
My thoughts would be to ensure $BAN$ is less than $90$, but that gives me a condition ($b^2 - a^2 > x^2$) which doesn't seem to work.

Ensuring $\angle BAN \le 90^\circ$ will include points to the right of $C$, which you do not want.
To ensure $N$ lies between $C$ and $D$, use the following compound inequality:
$$\angle BAC \le \angle BAN \le 90^\circ$$
Apply cosine, and reverse the inequality because it is a decreasing function:
$$\cos(90^\circ) \le \cos(\angle BAN) \le \cos(\angle BAC)$$
Use the definition of cosine for $\angle BAC$ and the cosine rule for $\angle BAN$:
$$0 \le \frac{a^2+x^2-b^2}{2ax} \le \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+BC^2}}$$
The left inequality simplifies to $b^2-a^2 \le x^2$ since $a$ and $x$ are non-zero. This is the exact opposite of what you derived ($b^2-a^2 \gt x^2$), which is where your mistake lies.

By "decreasing function", I mean that cosine is monotonically non-increasing in the closed interval $[0^\circ, 90^\circ]$
